# get entries with todays date

Tags: android, sqlite

I am trying to get all the rows with today's date, and return the number of rows I get. The app crashes when it loads.

**Method/SQLite query**

```
 public int getTodaysCount() {
    SQLiteDatabase db = smokinDBOpenHelper.getWritableDatabase();
    GregorianCalendar gc = new GregorianCalendar();
    SimpleDateFormat sdf = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd");
    String today = sdf.format(gc.getTime());

    Cursor cursor = db.rawQuery("SELECT * FROM " + smokinDBOpenHelper.INCIDENTS_TABLE
            + " WHERE " + KEY_DATE + " = DATETIME( ' " + today + " ' )", null);


    if (cursor.getCount() == 0 || !cursor.moveToFirst()) {

        throw new SQLException("No entries found");
    }

    return cursor.getCount();       
}
```

**Error from log**

```
03-20 12:26:25.913: E/AndroidRuntime(677): Caused by: 
android.database.sqlite.SQLiteException: near "==": syntax error (code 1): , while 
compiling: SELECT * FROM incidentsWHERE DATE_COLUMN == DATETIME( ' 2013-03-20 ' )
```

The error log seems to be telling me I'm not allowed to use the == . So if that's the case how do I perform this operation? With `<=` and `>=` ? Also is there a way to perform this query as a regular `query` as in not `rawQuery`?

**Example:**

```
db.query(SmokinDBOpenHelper.INCIDENTS_TABLE, new String[] 
            {KEY_ID, KEY_DATE}, KEY_DATE.equals(now) , null, null, null, null);
```

**Edit**

New Log error message:

```
03-20 12:56:22.103: E/AndroidRuntime(1153): Caused by:    
android.database.sqlite.SQLiteException: no such column: DATE_COLUMN (code 1): , while 
compiling: SELECT * FROM incidents WHERE DATE_COLUMN = DATETIME( ' 2013-03-20 ' )
```

**Incidents Table**

```
public static final String KEY_ID = "_id";

public static final String KEY_LOCATION = "location";
public static final int LOCATION_COLUMN = 1;

public static final String KEY_DATE = "date";
public static final int DATE_COLUMN = 2;

private SmokinDBOpenHelper smokinDBOpenHelper;

public MySmokinDatabase (Context context) {
    smokinDBOpenHelper = new SmokinDBOpenHelper(context, SmokinDBOpenHelper.DATABASE_NAME, 
            null, SmokinDBOpenHelper.DATABASE_VERSION);
}   

private static class SmokinDBOpenHelper extends SQLiteOpenHelper {

    private static final String DATABASE_NAME = "smokin.db";
    private static final String INCIDENTS_TABLE = "incidents";
    private static final int DATABASE_VERSION = 1;

    //SQL Statement to create a new database.

    private static final String DATABASE_CREATE = "create table " + 
        INCIDENTS_TABLE + " (" + 
        KEY_ID +  " integer primary key autoincrement, " +
        KEY_LOCATION + " text not null, " + 
        KEY_DATE + " text not null);";

    // Constructor

    public SmokinDBOpenHelper(Context context, String name, 
                   CursorFactory factory, int version) {
        super(context, name, factory, version);
    }

    //Called when no database exists in disk and the helper class needs
    //to create a new one. 

    @Override
    public void onCreate(SQLiteDatabase _db) {
        _db.execSQL(DATABASE_CREATE);
    }

    //Called when there is a database version mismatch meaning that the version
    //of the database on disk needs to be upgraded to the current version.

    @Override
    public void onUpgrade(SQLiteDatabase _db, int _oldVersion, int _newVersion) {
        // Log the version upgrade.
        Log.w("TaskDBAdapter", "Upgrading from version " + 
                              _oldVersion + " to " +
                              _newVersion + ", which will destroy all old data");

        // Upgrade the existing database to conform to the new version. Multiple 
        // previous versions can be handled by comparing _oldVersion and _newVersion
        // values.

        // The simplest case is to drop the old table and create a new one.
        _db.execSQL("DROP TABLE IF EXISTS " + INCIDENTS_TABLE);
        // Create a new one.
        onCreate(_db);
    }       
}
```

**Latest Error Message**

```
03-20 13:33:03.483: E/AndroidRuntime(1342): Caused by: android.database.SQLException: 
No entries found
```

**Insert Methods**

```
public void smokedHandler(View view) {
    Spinner spinner = (Spinner) findViewById(R.id.location_spinner);

    String s = spinner.getSelectedItem().toString();
    String d = model.getDates();

    mySmokinDatabase.insertSmokinValues(s, d);      

    refreshView();
}

public long insertSmokinValues(String s, String d) {
    SQLiteDatabase db = smokinDBOpenHelper.getWritableDatabase();
    ContentValues newSmokinValues = new ContentValues();

    newSmokinValues.put(KEY_DATE, s);
    newSmokinValues.put(KEY_LOCATION, d);

    return db.insert(SmokinDBOpenHelper.INCIDENTS_TABLE, null, newSmokinValues);
}

public String getDates() {
    GregorianCalendar gc = new GregorianCalendar();
    SimpleDateFormat sdf = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm");
    dates = sdf.format(gc.getTime());       

    return dates;
}
```

last note is that the values being stored in my database when i click the button right now are 
`s: Home` 
 `d: 2013-3-20 - 14:09`

As always thanks for any help!

Comment: I've edited my post to show the changes all of you have suggested. Help was appreciated but I now have a new error I posted above. This error seems impossible as there are already values in this column in this table in this db

Comment: If I run a query of all records, i get the number 13. If i run a query for records with todays date, i get 0. Now I have updated the post to show my insert methods and the methods showing the data they are inserting. I can't help but believe the query is not returning results because the entries are going in as `SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm")` and i am querying for entries as `SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd")`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> android.database.sqlite.SQLiteException: near "==": syntax error (code
>   1)

Your logcat says everything. Problem is **`==`** this is operator that returns boolean value and you need association.

```
String query = "SELECT * FROM " + smokinDBOpenHelper.INCIDENTS_TABLE
+ " WHERE DATE_COLUMN = DATETIME( ' " + today + " ' )", null);
```

### Note:

I recommend you to use placeholders instead of your hardcoded approach. It's cleaner and safer and you avoid problems what you forgot single quotes.

```
Cursor c = db.rawQuery(query, new String[] {today});
```

### Update:

> android.database.sqlite.SQLiteException: no such column: DATE_COLUMN
>   (code 1):

This means that your `DATE_COLUMN` not exist in your database. You defined it with constant KEY_DATE so you need change query into:

```
String query = "SELECT * FROM " + smokinDBOpenHelper.INCIDENTS_TABLE
    + " WHERE " + KEY_DATE + " = DATETIME( ' " + today + " ' )", null);
```

### Update 2:

My suggestion is to perform simple query without where clause and you will see if you have records in db:

```
String query = "SELECT * FROM " + smokinDBOpenHelper.INCIDENTS_TABLE", null);
```

Comment: thank you, I'm extremely new to sql, I was unaware of placeholders. I'm all about clean code though, so that seems like a much better approach. I've edited my post

Comment: posted logcat, which now just returns my own error message stating there are no records found. =(

Comment: @IrishWhiskey its not error it means that your cursor is empty. so any record in your database has provided date. try to create query without where clause and try it. see Update 2 in my answer.

Comment: I did your simple query and the `getCount()` it returns 13

Comment: @IrishWhiskey so now we can say that in your database not exist record with given date so this is not error but correct behaviour. now try to add new record with todays date and then perform query and you will see how it works.

Comment: Excellent sir, I am still getting 0. However I now understand how this works. I will post a little more code to help you understand and add a comment to my original post to further explain

Answer (score 3):

Use '=' sign instead of '==' sign as Sqlite does not support '==' sign in Query statement.
e.g:

```
    Cursor cursor = db.rawQuery(
        "SELECT * FROM "
        + smokinDBOpenHelper.INCIDENTS_TABLE +
        " WHERE " + 
        "DATE_COLUMN = DATETIME( ' " + today + " ' )", null);
```

Answer (score 2):

You are lacking a space between `incidents` and `WHERE`:

```
Cursor cursor = db.rawQuery(
            "SELECT * FROM "
            + smokinDBOpenHelper.INCIDENTS_TABLE +
            " WHERE " + 
            "DATE_COLUMN = DATETIME( ' " + today + " ' )", null);
```

Notice the space added before `WHERE`.

Also `==` should be a single `=`

Comment: I edited, my code, you were correct. However now I get a new error message. This one is really bad... I have no idea why there would be no such column. There are already values in that column

Comment: Can you post the structure of the `incidents` table? I don't think we can further help without that.

Comment: yes sir, done and done. Thanks for taking the time to look at what is probably a very silly question

Comment: Your `create_table` script doesn't even include a field named `DATE_COLUMN`, just one named `date` (and `id` and `location`). If that's the field you are referring to, then you should change all `DATE_COLUMN` references in the query SQL to `date`.

Comment: `DATE_COLUMN` just seems to be a variable specifying it's the second (on a zero-base index) field on the table, but on the SQL query you want to specify the column name, not the index (or a variable in your code).

Comment: That makes sense, but because I'm so new I have another question. Does this mean use the `KEY_DATE` because that doesn't seem to work. Or that I need to declare it somewhere as in my `SmokinDBOpenHelper` under the line `private static final int DATABASE_VERSION = 1;`

Comment: You are confusing the helper variables with the actual SQL. `KEY_DATE` is the name of a *variable* in your *code*: that's not in the _SQLite table_ at all (thus your SQL query doesn't know about `KEY_DATE`, `DATE_COLUMN`, or anything which only your code knows about). I think this discussion is leading WAY beyond the scope of the question (and probably Stack Overflow).

Comment: I think you're right and you guys have done a lot for me this afternoon. Thank you for your time. Between you and Sajmon I think I understand what's going on a little better.